# SQL Server 2012 find rows with overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this has been asked before, but I can't make any previous answers work for me, and most of them are many years old. I have the following table:

```
    ID   Start       End  
    1    1/1/2018    1/14/2018  
    1    1/15/2018   1/30/2018  
    1    1/20/2018   2/5/2018  
    2    2/1/2018    2/4/2018  
    2    2/1/2018    2/4/2018  
    2    2/20/2018   2/25/2018
    3    2/1/2018    2/15/2018
```

I need to be able to see the rows in my results that have overlapping date periods by ID.  These rows would be in my results:

```
    ID   Start       End  
    1    1/15/2018   1/30/2018  
    1    1/20/2018   2/5/2018  
    2    2/1/2018    2/4/2018  
    2    2/1/2018    2/4/2018
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.start < t.end and t2.end > t.start
             );
```

Comment: that gives me all 8 rows in my results, not just the overlapping ones...?

Comment: I need ONLY the overlapping rows in my results.  I should only get 4 rows.

Comment: @SheriAnderson . . . Your question doesn't state it, but I surmise that you want overlaps within a given `id`.